# Iterate on JSON Array using Robotframework

Tags: arrays, json, testing, robotframework, web-api-testing

Created a functionality(Thanks to NILS) wherein it dynamically fetch and count objects MOTOR and BIKELIST and get its bike type

```
${json}=    Evaluate    json.loads('''${response.text}''')      json
FOR     ${ob_list}      IN      @{json['bikesToAdd']['bikeList']}
    Log    remarkType: ${ob_list["bikeType"]}  console=True
    Should Contain       remarkType: ${ob_list["bikeType"]}      Mountain Bike
END
```

My end goal is get the BIKE LIST, BIKE TYPE and its Corresponding WHEELCOMMENT.
If i have 2 diffrent bike type the out put should be

1. BikeList, Mountain Bike, The nut cracker
2. Bikelist, Road, Test 1

however I'm encountering Keywords error and failed Key error on fetching wheel comment.

```
{
"bikesToAdd": {
    "bikeList": [
        {
            "bikeId": null,
            "bikeType": Mountain Bike,
            "bikeCommentList": [
                {
                    "wheelComment": “The Nut Cracker”,
                    "handlingComment": null,
                }
            ]
        },{
            "bikeId": null,
            "bikeType": Road,
            "bikeCommentList": [
                {
                    "wheelComment": null,
                    "handlingComment": null,
                }
            ]
        },
        
    ],"motorList": [
        {
            "motorListId": null,
            "motorListType": null,
            "motorList": [
                {
                    "wheelComment": “The White Cho”, 
                    "handlingComment": null,
                }
            ]
        },{
            
            "motorListId": null,
            "motorListType": null,
            "motorList": [
                {
                    "wheelComment": “The quick brown fox”,
                    "handlingComment": null,
                }
            ]
        },
        
    ]
```

}

failed: SyntaxError: invalid syntax (, line 1) (FOR LOOP ISSUE)
was injecting counter variable next to the `['bikelist'][${counte_var}]` json query and it keeps prompting an error

Comment: Please include the actual error as part of your question.

Comment: You're going to need to be a bit more specific. What line of your code is causing that error?

Comment: in for bryan FOR   FOR     ${ob_list}      IN      @{json['bikesToAdd']['bikeList']}

I can't put a counter variable next to bikelist to get the comment.

Comment: It doesn't look like valid json? - "The quick brown fox" should be enclosed in double quotes, as well as the other strings

Comment: I just forgot to enclosed it.